# ¿Saben que está pasando aquí? Esta función recursiva retorna en forma correcta una variable que nunca fué modificada en ningún bloque del código

Tags: javascript, nodejs

En esta función potencia recursiva devuelve la variable 'resultado' que nunca fue modificada en el código y sorprendentemente da el resultado esperado.Según el código debería retornar 1. ¿Saben porque?

```js
function potencia (num,eleva){
  let resultado = 0;
  if (!eleva){
   resultado=1;
   }else
   {
    resultado = num * potencia (num,eleva-1);
    }
  
  return resultado;
 }
 console.log(potencia(2,3)); //8
```

Comment: Porque dices tu que debe retornar 1?

Comment: Creo que hay un error en mi lógica sobre lo que en realidad devuelve el 'return'

Answer (score 2):

La función `potencia` se llama con los argumentos `2` y `3`. Cuando `eleva` es igual a `3`, la condición `!eleva` evalúa a `false` porque `3` no es igual a `0` (es decir, `if (!eleva)` no cumple). Por lo tanto, la ejecución sigue el camino del bloque `else` y se realiza la multiplicación recursiva.

Para explicarme mejor, la función se llama sucesivamente de la siguiente manera:

```
//   En cada loop "eleva" resta "1"---v
// potencia(2, 3) llama a potencia(2, 2). -> primera recursión (va al else, no cumple "!eleva")
// potencia(2, 2) llama a potencia(2, 1). -> segunda recursión (va al else, no cumple "!eleva")
// potencia(2, 1) llama a potencia(2, 0). -> tercera recursión (cumple "!eleva", va al if y se detiene el loop)
```

En la tercera recursión, al llamar a `potencia(2, 0)` la condición `if (!eleva)` se cumple porque `0` (que es el valor actual de `eleva`) se evalúa como falso en la condición booleana, ya que no vuelve a llamar a la misma función, más solo devuelve el valor `1`. Por lo tanto, se establece `resultado` en `1` y se detiene la recursión.

Entonces, el valor final calculado es: `2` * `2` * `2` * `1` = `8`.

En donde:

- El primer `2` es el valor de `num` (que nunca ha sido modificada).
- El segundo y tercer `2` son el valor de `eleva` ya que cumplieron el `else` en el primer y segundo bucle (`3` - `1` = `2`).
- El número `1` es el valor de `eleva` obtenido en el tercer bucle, ya que cumplió el `if (!eleva)` por tomar el valor de `0`.

Aunque parezca que `resultado` no se cambie en las llamadas recursivas, su valor se acumula y multiplica a medida que se va regresando a través de las llamadas recursivas, ya que véase que al final tienes:

```
return resultado;
```

Y en base a esto, devuelve el valor de cada llamada recursiva que haces aquí:

```
resultado = num * potencia(num, eleva - 1);
```

O también al caso de ingresar al `if`:

```
resultado = 1;
```

Y habrá un momento en el que la llamada recursiva se detendrá (cuando cumpla `if (!eleva)`), teniendo un cálculo final acumulado en `resultado` y retornando ese último resultado final.

Comment: Enntiendo, en el caso base al cambiar el valor de 'resultado' a 1 ya puedo ir volviendo en la recursion porque ya van a haber valores para multiplicar y el 'return' me devuelde el valor de la multiplicacion y no el que fue asignado dentro del if. Muy buena tu explicación.

Answer (score 2):

Considera este ejemplo con las *entradas* y la *salida*.

| Entrada | Salida |
| --- | --- |
| 2, 3 | 8 |
| 3, 4 | 81 |

El código está realizando esta lógica:

```
2^3 = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8    
3^4 = 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 = 81
```

Esta es la forma en que el código se está ejecutando.

*La primera instrucción es llamar a la function con los argumentos* **2**    *y* **3**.

```
function potencia (num,eleva)
```

*Ahora la variable* `resultado` *está inicializada e*n **cero**.

```
let resultado = 0;
```

*En la condición declarada, verifica si* `eleva` *es igual a* **0**.

```
 if (!eleva)
```

El valor no es **cero**, ahora en la function `else`, se llama a sí misma nuevamente pero con `eleva`**-** `1` como segundo argumento.

```
potencia (num,eleva-1);
```

*En el bloque* `else` *se realiza el cálculo:*

**-** *Los detalles ahora son que* `num` *vale 2 y* `eleva` *vale* `3`**-**`1` cuando se llama a la function de `potencia` de manera **recursiva**. *Los argumentos son* `2` *y* `2`, *

*La variable* `num` *tiene un valor de* **2**, *que se multiplica con la function recursiva cuyos argumentos son* **2** *y* **2**.

**2** `*` **2** `*` **2** *=* **8**

*Para la* **segunda** *entrada.*

*El número es* **3** *y la potencia es* **4**`-`**1**.

La function `potencia` *se llama recursivamente con los argumentos* **3** *y* **3**.

*La function devuelve el valor* **9**, *que será* **3** *elevado a* **3**.

**3** `*` **3** `*` **3** `*` **3**  = **81**

**Paso** *a* **paso**:

```
Entrada: num = 2, eleva = 3

Inicializa el resultado en 0.

Verifica si eleva es 0.

Si eleva es 0, retorna 1.
   De lo contrario, retorna num * potencia(num, eleva - 1).
   Llama a la función potencia de forma recursiva, definiendo los argumentos num = 2 y eleva = 3 - 1 = 2.
   La función potencia retornará 4, que es 2 elevado a la 2.
   Multiplica num (2) por el valor retornado por la función potencia (4).

El resultado es 8.
```

Lo que está sucediendo es que la función de potencia se llama a sí misma de manera recursiva dos veces.
La recursión es un tipo de código que se llama a sí mismo varias veces hasta que resuelve el problema propuesto.